# Oracle Forms: have a specific column on some rows not store a value in the database?

Tags: oracle, forms, builder

**Requirements**

Here are the simplified requirements.  The end goal is to be able to display data about an item, or print labels using the saved data. The solution is being created in Oracle Forms Builder

- Attribute Definition form

  - Designed to define attributes.
  - Attribute configuration details are stored in an attribute
    definition table
  - Attributes can be either a manually entered
    values, or SQL driven

    - SQL Example: Case Weight (uses the Item's
      Case UOM conversion rate multiplied by the item's unit weight)
    - Manual Example: Color of item
  - When SQL driven, a select statement is saved in the attribute configuration

    - Tokens like `:INVENTORY_ITEM_ID` are used in the SQL, and will be replaced with
      values by the form when the SQL is evaluate.
- Item Attribute Assignment form

  - Designed to link attributes to an item
  - Form includes a list of attributes assigned to an item

    - Records that link the attribute to the item are saved in the
      database
    - Records store the attribute ID, Item ID and the attribute
      value (if applicable)
    - List should be in a single block.
  - The form
    allows additional assignments of attributes (which defined in first
    form)
  - Items can have SQL and Manual type attributes assigned to
    them.

    - Form allows "manual" values to be updated at any time by the
      user
    - Form derives SQL values, displays them in the "value" field,
      but the value field should be disabled so the user can't edit it.
  - Upon querying an item or assigning a new attribute

    - SQL values should be derived/evaluated
    - Manual entered values should be pulled
      from the tables "value" column

**Problem**

We don’t want the form to save the SQL derived values to the table.

Is there a way to have a specific column on some rows not store a value in the database?  These would be the rows that contain the SQL derived values, which are displayed in the disabled value cell, and derived when an item is queried, or an attributes is assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but you really should implement table handlers for your Forms, rather than relying on Oracle Forms to do your DML for you.

By "implement table handlers", I mean, set the block's "`DML Data Target Type`" property to "`Use Transactional Triggers`".

Then, code the `ON-INSERT`, `ON-UPDATE`, etc triggers for your block to call PL/SQL (passing in the appropriate values to insert, update, etc from your block).

In your PL/SQL, you can insert each column exactly where and how you want it, or don't insert a column at all, which is what you're after here.

If you are using the Oracle e-Business Suite, this is documented in the *Oracle Applications Developer's Guide*, chapter 10 ("Using PL/SQL in Oracle E-Business Suite: Coding Item, Event, and Table Handlers").

Comment: Thank you! I'll pass this on to our developer who was having the problem. I'll report back ASAP to let you know how it worked out.